# Testing the content of a flash message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, flask

I would like to test whether a flash message contains certain text. So I have the line:

```
response = tester.post('login',
        data=dict(
        username='test', password='lol'), follow_redirects=True)
assert 'Welcome back!' in response.data
```

This however fails with the error message:

```
 assert 'Welcome back!' in response.data
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: So, the problem here is: `a bytes-like object is required` and you are giving a `str`. So, I think you can do:  `str.encode(response.data)` and then `assert`.

Comment: In this simple case, prepend your string with `b`, resulting in `b'Welcome back!'`

Comment: @Ruturaj Whenever I do `str.encode(response.data)` followed by `assert` it tells me TypeError: descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to 'bytes' object

Comment: @MichaelButscher I prepend the string with `b`, doing `b'Welcome back!` and tells me `AssertionError` but nothing else, I have no clue why

Comment: That's because your `response.data` may not have `Welcome back!` in it. So, you can use `try-catch` to catch that error.

Comment: @Ruturaj I actually do, whenever I run the program and login correctly the flash message "Welcome back!" shows up. On the actual file `app.py` I have this part of code that basically happens if the login is correct `session["log"] = True`
                                                                                                     
     `flash("Welcome back!", "success")` So I do not know why that is happening?

Comment: I just added the answer. Have you tried to print the `response.data`?

Comment: Yes I have, I managed to get it to work! Thank you guys for the help!

Comment: @Ruturaj I just noticed that when I run the file it says `OK` but prior to that it goes to the catch part Assertion failed! is there a reason why? Also I had to change the catch to `except` because it said invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MichaelButscher suggested, you can do:

`assert b'Welcome back!' in response.data`

This is because your `response.data` has a `<class 'bytes'>` type. So, you need to match your 'Welcome back!' string to bytes.

In your case, you can fix your code like this:

```
response = tester.post('login',
        data=dict(
        username='test', password='lol'), follow_redirects=True)
try:
    assert 'Welcome back!' in response.data
except AssertionError:
    print("Assertion failed!")
```

So, for e.g. response.data = `b"xxxxWelcome back!xxxx"` then it matches it, otherwise not.

Make sure: your string exactly matches with your input (or the string to be asserted) and also make sure that case-sensitivity also matters here.

Comment: I just noticed that when I run the file it says `OK` but prior to that it goes to the catch part `Assertion failed!` is there a reason why? Also I had to change the catch to `except` because it said invalid syntax.

Comment: yes, I fixed that. so, what you mean is `response.data` prints `ok`? basically assert try to match the exact string, if it couldn't then throws an error.